# np.savetxt() does not save file when using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, numpy, windows-task-scheduler

I have a script that I'd like to run daily and found [a very helpful article](https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/) on how to use the Windows Task Scheduler. As the tutorial instructed, I made a `.bat` file:

```
"C:\Python\python.exe" "C:\Python\mee6APIData\mee6DataGetter.py"
pause
```

and whenever I run this file, the resulting `.csv` file gets written properly. However, when the scheduler runs the same `.bat` file there is no file written. I do get a permission error as well as a traceback that might help:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\mee6APIData\mee6DataGetter.py", line 34, in <module>
        loop.run_until_complete(job())
    File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
        return future.result()
    File "C:\Python\mee6APIData\mee6DataGetter.py", line 31, in job
        await readData(1)
    File "C:\Python\mee6APIData\mee6DataGetter.py", line 28, in readData
        np.savetxt(date + '.csv', initArray, delimiter=', ', comments='', fmt='%s', encoding='utf8')
    File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in savetxt
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1377, in savetxt
        open(fname, 'wt').close()
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '03-22-2020.csv'
```

but there are no permission errors when running the program manually. I did find [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/902812/why-doesnt-my-python-script-save-the-file-when-i-use-task-scheduler) asked already, but I have not gotten this method to work either. Is there something that I'm missing? Does the Task Scheduler need to run the `.bat` file as an administrator? Any help is appreciated!

#### edit:

As an example for my error, the following code (exampleCode.py, which is in a folder named 'mee6APIData') works properly when ran manually:

```
import numpy as np
dataArray = ['user_ID', 'server_name', 'server_xp', 'date']
np.savetxt('example.csv', dataArray, delimiter=', ', comments='', fmt='%s', encoding='utf8')
```

and the corresponding `.bat` file:

```
"C:\Python\python.exe" "C:\Python\mee6APIData\exampleCode.py"
pause
```

following the aforementioned [tutorial](https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/), the error should reveal itself as using the task scheduler does not save the file.

Comment: Did you try with an absolute path for the result file? The task scheduler might not have the same working directory or mounted network drives etc.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why that works, but it did! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`np.savetxt()` should have the save file written to the absolute path and not a working directory:

```
np.savetxt('C:\Python\mee6APIData\example.csv', dataArray, delimiter=', ', comments='', fmt='%s', encoding='utf8')
```